# Notch or Bandstop filter and preparing data for it

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and signal processing methods, but i am trying to use its filter properties over a set of data I have. I have a collection of amplitude values obtained at different timestamps. When this is plotted, I get a waveform with several peaks that I can identify. I then perform calculations to derive the time between each consecutive peak and I want to eliminate the rates that are around the range of 48-52peaks per second.

What would be the correct way to go about processing this data step by step? Would a bandstop or notch filter be better if I want to eliminate those frequencies and not attenuate it simply? I am completely lost in the parameters required to feed into the filters for this. Please help...

Answer (score 1):

periodogram is OK, but I would suggest using pwelch instead. It makes a more reasonable PSD estimate and the default parameters are well thought out (Hann windows, 50% overlap of segments, etc.)

If what you want is to remove signals in a wide band (e.g. 48-52 Hz) equally, rather than a single and unchanging frequency, than a bandstop filter is ideal. For example:

```
fs = 2048;
y = rand(fs*8, 1);
[b,a] = ellip(4, 2, 40, [46 54]/(fs/2));
yy = filter(b,a,y);
```

This will use a 4th order elliptic bandstop filter to filter the random data variable 'y'. filtfilt.m is also a nice function; it applies the filter forwards and backwards so you get twice the filter action and none of the phase lag or dispersion.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing something similar to what you are doing.
I am processing a lot of signals from the Inertial Measurement Unit and motor drives. They all are asynchronously obtained, i.e. they all have very different timestamp and also very different acquisition frequency.

First thing I did was to interpolate all signals data in order to have all signals with same timestamp. You can use the matlab function **interp** to do this.

After this, you will have all signals with same sample frequency and also timestamp, which will be good in further analysis.

Ok, another thing you can do to analyse the frequency of the peaks is to perform the fourier transform. For beginners i advice the use of **periodogram** function and not the **fft** function.

Imagine you signal is **x** and your sample frequency (after interpolation) is **Fs**.
You can now use the function **periodogram** available in matlab like this:

[P,f] = periodogram(x,[],[length(t)],Fs);

This will give the power vs frequency of your signal. After that you will be able to plot and take a look at the frequencies of your signal. In other words, you be able to see the frequencies of the signals that make your acquired signal.
Plot the data this way:

plot(f,P);  or    semilogy(f,P);

The second is the same thing as the first, but with a logarithmic scale.

After this analysis you can use the **Filter Desing and Analysis Tool** to design you filter. Just type **fdatool** in matlab and it will open the design window. Choose the filter type, the cut and pass frequencies and click in design. This tool is very intuitive.
After designing you can export the filter to workspace.

Finally you can use the filter you designed in your signal to see if its what you wanted. 
Use the functions **filter** os **filtfilt** for this.

Search in the web of the matlab help for the **functions** I wrote to get more details.
There are a lot of examples availables too.

I hope I could help you.
Good luck.